# what is nproc and nofile in ulimits?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ulimit

I would like to know what nofile and nproc in ulimits is for, preferably with examples. Specifically, what is their role in database?

Comment: do you know about a thing called searching the internet? When I search for `linux nofile` there are 490000 results. When I serach for `linux nproc` there are 125000 results. .....

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at coding a solution to your problem. Sorry, but **requests for tutorials, research**, tools, recommendations, libraries, and free coding services are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With respect to mongodb the two parameters are as follows:

**nofile:** `-n: file descriptors`

- This ulimit settings parameters tells how many file descriptor a mongodb process can use. MongoDB internally uses file for storing connections, journal files, indexes and datafiles.
- MongoDB recommeneds to set `nofile` to 64000. However, you may need to change it to higher values based on your requirement(with `WiredTiger` storage engine in particular). Provided you do testing on your environments using these values.

**nproc:**  `-u: processes/threads`

- MongoDB uses processes to track each internal thread or `pthread` as a system process. e.g replication thread
- MongoDB shows a startup warning if `nproc` is not set as expected. This is generally set as 1/2 of the `nofile` for mongodb deployments

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable time I hav one scenario that we have add one secondry server n started intial sync with parameter only nofile upto 64000 and nproc upto 1024. it is feasible for new secondry to stay up.

Comment: If you look at the mongodb init script, it sets the nproc to -u 64000. In your case setting lower value will end up sending a startup warning and may cause any possible problems when nproc(1024) eventually reached

Comment: as u have describe me above what is nproc as per that when processes used MongoDB will increase then issue will occur ryt

Comment: setting this value to lesser than what required will cause an issue